# Changing a data attr value

Tags: jquery

I am using a plugin called slim scroll for some scroll bars on my page, my only issue with them is that they are not responsive. So while the 100px height looks nice when stretched out, it doesn't look so wonderful when the browser size is reduced.

So to solve this issue I was trying to do some jQuery to do some widowWidth and then change the data element controlling the height.

So I have tried something like this, but it seems to be just changing the actual height element instead of the data-height

```
function slimScrollResize(){
    loadWidth = $(window).width();
    if(loadWidth <= 1138){
        $('.slim-scroll').data('height', '300');
    }
}
```

So then I tried changing

```
$('.slim-scroll').data('height', '300');
```

to

```
$('.slim-scroll').data('data-height', '300');
```

and now it's not changing anything.

Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be awesome!

A js fiddle to help debug...and note I cannot change the data name because of the plugin.
http://jsfiddle.net/575VZ/1/

Comment: Please check out a custom scroll I've made.. maybe it can be helpful: http://codepen.io/mkhoudary/pen/bqycE

Comment: maybe you also want to have a look at jquery $( window ).resize(function() {
 //your function here
});

Comment: @MohammedR.El-Khoudary I'm already using a plugin that the template I'm using gave me...why would I want to switch to something  different?

Comment: @caramba My resize is working fine, it's the data attribute I seem to be having issue with.

Comment: can you also show your markup and may create a fiddle

Comment: @caramba I just added a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
$('.slim-scroll').attr('data-height', '300');
```

Comment: +1,  or prop() as seems to be the better option nowadays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: I just tried this, it's doing the same thing and just changing the actual height

Comment: I don't think you can set data attribute using `prop()` though.

Comment: pretty sure ya can bro - im muckin around with a fiddle ill send on in a bit

Comment: @zazvorniki Can you set up a fiddle to replicate your problem?

Comment: @Felix When using it and changing it to data-height it seems to stop working though.

Comment: @Felix I just added one.

Comment: @zazvorniki You need to use `attr` instead of `prop`

Comment: @Felix It still does the same thing if you switch it to attr

Comment: @zazvorniki You've a syntax error at the last line. It should be `});`. Check working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/575VZ/2/